Issue with this solution for the probability puzzle
The problem:
100 distinct positive amounts are written on slips of paper and mixed. A slip is drawn at random and we must decide whether that is the largest amount or not. If we decide it is, we win if we are correct; otherwise we get nothing. If we decide against the amount written on the first slip, we must choose or refuse the next slip, and so until we choose one or else the slips are exhausted. How should we make our decision?
I started with the following approach:
Firstly, let's replace the amounts by their ranks. So the slips now have $1$ to $100$ written on them.
Suppose that we calculate the maximum till first $k$ elements, and then choose the first element that is bigger than that maximum. To calculate the winning probability:
$$P(Win) = \sum^{99}_{i=k}P(Win|F_i)P(F_i)$$
where $F_i$ is the event that the maximum of first $k$ elements is $i$.
As far as I can see, $F_i \cap F_j = \phi$ for all $i\neq j$. And $F_k \cup F_{k+1} \cup \dots \cup F_{100}$ contains the complete domain. So this is a valid partition.
Now $$P(F_i) = \frac{\binom{i-1}{k-1}*k!}{\binom{100}{k}*k!} = \frac{\binom{i-1}{k-1}}{\binom{100}{k}}$$
Also, $$P(Win|F_i) = \frac{(99-i)!}{(100-i)!}$$
since in the last $(100-k)$ elements, there will definitely be the slips: $i+1, i+2, \dots 100$. So total possible arrangemenets of these is the denominator and the numerator is the number of arrangements with $100$ in the start.
But on coding and plotting the graph of the above function, I am getting the maximum at $k=1$, which is wrong.
Can somebody point out the issue with my logic?

"The king to test a candidate for the position of wise man...," "How should the wise man make his decision?" So, is he auditioning for the role of "wise man", or does he already hold that title? And if he is auditioning for the role of wise man, why is it that all he wins is the biggest dowry, and not the job (which is never mentioned after the first sentence)? Anyway, this is often called The Secretary Puzzle, and I'm sure you'll find it has been discussed on this website before.

In particular, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4404051/choosing-the-largest-dowry-or-secretary-problem and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4404294/alternative-strategy-to-choose-the-largest-random-number and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3879259/how-to-solve-the-probability-of-winning-this-game-with-this-strategy

@GerryMyerson Kindly read the description

I did. ${}{}{}$

@GerryMyerson so I already have alternative solutions but what I need is the issue with my solution particularly. I can't seem to find it. The links you mentioned do not answer my issue.

Those are just the first three links I found. I'm sure there are many more, and of course many discussions elsewhere on the web and in books. Also, this website is not just for you. Other users may come along who are interested in seeing approaches other than yours, and I have given them some leads. And what about the whole dowry versus wise man thing?

@GerryMyerson for that kindly read the links you shared. Thanks for your kind help sir.

I have edited this problem to remove the patriarchical scenario where woman are treated like prizes for men. I advise everyone to avoid perpetuating sexist scenarios like this.

Your problem is different from the secretary problem because you get the largest amount if you have guessed right or you get nothing In the secretary problem you always get whatever you choose

One thing that I found in one of those links is that although you have presented the problem as your own invention, ztart, in fact you copied it word-for-word from some other source (not so obvious, now that user @Greg has done some editing). This is called plagiarism, and we take a dim view of it here.

@GerryMyerson If you can help with the math, then it would be great if you could help. If you can't please don't waste your time here. Nowhere in the post have I said that the problem is "my invention".
I thought this site was for mathematical discussions, what I am getting here is lectures on sexism, plagiarism, basically everything except the actual math.

You posted word-for-word and without attribution a long paragraph from some other source. It's not too late to make things right by citing your source.

Ethics are important in any discussion, @ztart14578. You are part of an interconnected community, and you need to avoid actions that harm others. The fact that you deem that feedback a waste of time is just a sign that you still need these "lectures" on ethical behavior.

Is this not a secreatary problem?

For those users who don't have enough points to see deleted material, OP has posted, "The solution I wrote is correct. The code I wrote was wrong. On reverifying, the plots for my function and the standard solution match." I think we're done here.
